# Umbraco order by expire date

Tags: c#, loops, razor, umbraco

I've created a simple loop below and I want to order this loop by its umbraco "Unpublish at" property. In my head it should be this :-

```
@foreach (var example in CurrentPage.Children.OrderBy("expireDate"))
{
    //Do Stuff//
}
```

This would be similar to Umbracos createDate but isn't working. Anybody got any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As @nsgocev describes, you cannot do this directly in Razor, however, you should not access the Document object in your razor either as this will hit the database.

Ideally what you should do is a little work but worth it:

- Create a new date property on your base document type called something like "expiryDate"
- Create an event that will set this field when the page is published and the "Unpublish" field has a property set.

This is a very good habit to get into, expanding Umbraco in such a way. Something like the following:

```
public class ExpiryDateEvent : IApplicationEventHandler 
{

    public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        ContentService.Published += ContentService_Published;
    }

    void ContentService_Published(IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> e)
    {
        var entity = e.Entity;

        if (entity.HasProperty("expiryDate") && e.entity.ExpireDate.HasValue)
        {
             entity.SetValue("expiryDate", e.Entity.ExpireDate.Value);

             sender.Save(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

The good thing about this is that it has so many applications for other scenarios. The one thing you do *not* want to be doing is hitting your database using the Document object in your UI.